# Cookiesdirective and Statcounter

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, directive

I have implemented cookiesdirective.js which can be found here cookiesdirective.com and Statcounter code is not working. I am using the following code (DoYourOwnSite, standard):

```
var sc_project=9181072; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="328a83d2"; 
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www."); 
document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" + scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
```

Since cookiesdirective.js requires to remove the  tags, I have removed them, but it is still not working. On the other hand, Google Analytics code is working without a problem. I am sure it is about changing the code a bit so it will work inside another javascript, but I do not now how to do it.

Thanks, 
Goran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to change the statcounter code a bit:

```
var sc_project=xxxxxxxxxx; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
var imported = document.createElement('script'); 
imported.type = 'text/javascript'; 
imported.async = true;
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www.");
imported.src = scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter_xhtml.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(imported, s);
```

Thanks anyway.